# Reference error: can't find variable: error

Tags: react-native, react-redux

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xvKR.jpg)

this is the error I'm getting when I run npx react-native  run-android
I was writing the code and everything was fine till I decided to take a break then I came back and wanted to continue but this error came up so I'm not even sure where the error is from, so any help would be appreciated

I tried these fixes

react-native link (i usually do this after install a dependency or package then restart)
./gradlew clean
npm install

I'm using an older version following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1T4mE8_ZKv8&t=1s) video youtube

These are the only places error is used in my code
I'm trying to fetch market data from coingecko

**marketReducer.js**

```
import { ActionSheetIOS } from 'react-native';
import * as marketActions from './marketActions';

const initialState = {
    myHoldings: [],
    coins: [],
    error: null,
    loading: false
}

const marketReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case marketActions.GET_HOLDINGS_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case marketActions.GET_HOLDINGS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                myHoldings: action.payload.myHoldings
            }
        case marketActions.GET_HOLDINGS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
            }
        case marketActions.GET_COIN_MARKET_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case marketActions.GET_COIN_MARKET_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                coins: action.payload.coins
            }
        case marketActions.GET_COIN_MARKET_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**marketActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
    
    
    export const GET_HOLDINGS_BEGIN = "GET_HOLDINGS_BEGIN"
    export const GET_HOLDINGS_SUCCESS = "GET_HOLDINGS_SUCCESS"
    export const GET_HOLDINGS_FAILURE = "GET_HOLDINGS_FAILURE"
    export const GET_COIN_MARKET_BEGIN = "GET_COIN_MARKET_BEGIN"
    export const GET_COIN_MARKET_SUCCESS = "GET_COIN_MARKET_SUCCESS"
    export const GET_COIN_MARKET_FAILURE = "GET_COIN_MARKET_FAILURE"
    
    //Holding / My Holdings
    
    export const getHoldingsBegin = () => ({
        type: GET_HOLDINGS_BEGIN
    })
    
    export const getHoldingsSuccess = (myHoldings) => ({
        type: GET_HOLDINGS_SUCCESS,
        payload: { myHoldings }
    });
    
    export const getHoldingsFailure = (error) = ({
        type: GET_HOLDINGS_FAILURE,
        payload: { error }
    })
    
    export function getHoldings(holdings = [], currency = "usd", orderBy = "market_cap_desc", sparkline = true, priceChangePerc = "7d", perPage = 10, page = 1) {
    
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(getHoldingsBegin())
    
            let ids = holdings.map((item) => { return item.id }).join(",");
            let apiUrl = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=${currency}&order=${orderBy}&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}&sparkline=${sparkline}&price_change_percentage=${priceChangePerc}&ids=${ids}`
    
            return axios({
                url: apiUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                header: {
                    Accept: "application/json"
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log("GetHoldings")
                console.log(response)
                if (response.state == 200) {
                    //Massage data
                    let myHoldings = response.data.map((item) => {
                        //Retrieve our current holdings -> current quantity
                        let coin = holdings.find(a => a.id == item.id)
    
                        //Price from 7 days ago
                        let price7d = item.current_price / (1 + item.price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency * 0.01)
    
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            symbol: item.symbol,
                            name: item.name,
                            img: item.image,
                            current_price: item.current_price,
                            price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency: item.price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency,
                            holding_value_change_7d: (item.current_price - price7d) * coin.qty,
                            sparkline_in_7d: {
                                value: item.sparkline_in_7d.price.map((price) => {
                                    return price * coin.qty
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
    
                    dispatch(getHoldingsSuccess(myHoldings))
                } else {
                    dispatch(getHoldingsFailure(response.data));
                }
            }).catch((error) => { dispatch(getHoldingsFailure(error)); });
        }
    
    }
    
    // Coin Market
    
    export const getCoinMarketBegin = () => ({
        type: GET_COIN_MARKET_BEGIN
    })
    
    export const getCoinMarketSuccess = (coins) => ({
        type: GET_COIN_MARKET_SUCCESS,
        payload: { coins }
    })
    
    export const getCoinMarketFailure = (error) => ({
        type: GET_COIN_MARKET_FAILURE,
        payload: { error }
    })
    
    export function getCoinMarket(currency = "usd", orderBy = "market_cap_desc", sparkline = true, priceChangePerc = "7d", perPage = 10, page = 1) {
    
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(getCoinMarketBegin())
    
            let apiUrl = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=${currency}&order=${orderBy}&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}&sparkline=${sparkline}&price_change_percentage=${priceChangePerc}
            `
    
            return axios({
                url: apiUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                header: {
                    Accept: 'application/json'
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                if (response.state == 200) {
                    dispatch(getCoinMarketSuccess(response.data))
                }else{
                    dispatch(getCoinMarketFailure(response.data))
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                dispatch(getCoinMarketFailure(error))
            })
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: I think that the problem is about your written code. How about you search your project folder and find the existence of 'error' ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just added the code i used error variable, could not find the mistake